# MySQL id not saving in order (Laravel in production)

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, orm, heroku

[image]

I'm really confused about this..

So, I created a Laravel app and hosted it on Heroku. I'm using ClearDB extension to be able to use MySQL. Problem is: when I save a new User on my DB, it is not being saved in ID order.

I got id 1, then id 11 for the second register, then id 21 for the third... Then I deleted them and tried again, and I got id 31. I think, there's a pattern, huh? It's going +10, +10... But why?

Look, the code I'm using to save a new register is only: DB::table('registers')->insert($registerData);

On the $registerData variable, I have only the following data: name, e-mail, a url for the picture and birth date.

Even my "migrations" table is in this order: 1, 11, 21, 31...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the auto_increment on your tables is set to 10 instead of 1.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_increment_increment';`